# Showing images using Firebase Remote Config

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I just started using the Remote Config in the Firebase console. It's a great tool and it works fine, but I can't figure out how I can 'push' different images (drawables) to my app using the parameters in the console. Is this even possible and if yes, how do I use this in my app?

My current MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TEAM1 = "team1";
private static final String TEAM2 = "team2";
private FirebaseRemoteConfig mFirebaseRemoteConfig;
private TextView mTeam1Text;
private TextView mTeam2Text;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTeam1Text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team1);
    mTeam2Text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team2);


    Button fetchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    fetchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            fetchDiscount();
        }
    });

    mFirebaseRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();
    FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings configSettings = new FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder()
            .setDeveloperModeEnabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            .build();
    mFirebaseRemoteConfig.setConfigSettings(configSettings);
    mFirebaseRemoteConfig.setDefaults(R.xml.remote_config_defaults);
    fetchDiscount();
}
private void fetchDiscount() {
    mTeam1Text.setText(mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getString(TEAM1));
    mTeam2Text.setText(mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getString(TEAM2));

    long cacheExpiration = 3600;
    if (mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getInfo().getConfigSettings().isDeveloperModeEnabled()) {
        cacheExpiration = 0;
    }

    mFirebaseRemoteConfig.fetch(cacheExpiration)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Vernieuwd",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        mFirebaseRemoteConfig.activateFetched();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Vernieuwen mislukt",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}
}
```

The remote config defaults:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<defaultsMap>
<entry>
    <key>vernieuwen</key>
    <value>true</value>-
</entry>
```

[image]
Can you guys tell me if this is even possible and if so, how that works? Please let me know if you need more information?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Remote Config is for sending simple values to your app. It cannot be used to deliver images.

The typical way to handle this scenario is to separate the image out from Remote Config. For example: you could store them in Firebase Storage or Firebase Hosting.

Then in Remote Config you'd have a parameter that contains the URL of the image to display:

```
startupImage: https://yourapp.firebaseapp.com/path/to/todays/image.jpg
```